One Page IDP issued by Govt. Of India not acceptable in Japan
I will be visiting Japan soon and am planning to rent a car in Tokyo from any rental agency. I have a concern that in my region/state(In India), a booklet format IDP is not issued by the government.
The government follows a A4 size page format for the IDP which includes details like Local driving license number, Address, goverment stamp, validity period, etc.
The "Geneva convention 1949" line is also mentioned on it.
The problem is that many agencies don't recognise this one page IDP and expect the old booklet format one only.
I would really appreciate if you can share any work around for this issue?
I contacted my regional AA/RTO too, but that didn't help any.
I have also attached a sample IDP from my region for reference.

Please let me know what can I do. I really wanted to drive around in Japan as it has been a bucket list kinda item.
If you have been in a similar situation, request you to kindly share your experience.
Thanks a lot!

"many agencies don't recognise this one page IDP": is that from your personal experience, official information, or second-hand reports?

Is driving the important thing, or would a rail pass be an option?

Is your local region IDP the only IDP available to Indian drivers' license holders? Can you source an IDP from another provider who issues the standard multi-page IDP form?

Have you tried getting the IDP from the Automobile Association of Upper India instead?

Note that whoever refuses the document shown is quite justified to do so. The 1949 convention explicitly states in Annex 10: "Dimensions: 105 x 148 mm. Colours: cover: grey pages: white"

@NateEldredge this is from the experiences of many friends there who had a similar situation

@Traveller yes, driving is kund of a bucket list for me. Planned to drive the Tokyo Izu route

@DavidRecallsMonica yes I can source it from other sources. But that won't be Government sources naa? Private companies for the booklet do are there. But will non-official companies be accepted, I am not sure.

@jcaron No I didn't try from this. Since it is not an official source for getting the IDP. Do you happen to know of any success stories with this one?

Actually, the AAUI is the official provider of the IDP in your area. https://internationaldrivingpermit.org/country/india/

According to the non-governmental source cited by jcaron in Comments, four organizations in India issue IDPs. Because the AAUP's IDP does not conform with the standard IDP format, the OP should obtain an IDP from one of the other three providers in India.

@DavidRecallsMonica, do you mean the AAUI's * IDP? I don't find AAUP in the list. On which parameter it doesn't conform to standard IDP?

@DavidRecallsMonica, I have no other option than to apply from AAUI! should I just forfeit it?

Why do you have no other options? Three other India organizations issue IDPs.

@DavidRecallsMonica, this is because the the organisation issuing an IDP is tied to the address you live in. Can you please point what exactly is not conforming with the standard format?

In a quick look around the internet haven't seen any evidence that the booklet is an "old" format. The Vienna Convention on Road Traffic, last amended 2006, states in Annex 7:

The permit shall be a booklet in format A 6 (148 x 105 mm). The cover shall be grey and the inside pages white.

Additionally, as others have said, certain information in the booklet must be in multiple languages, including at least English, Russian and Spanish. So unfortunately it seems to me like your state is not issuing valid IDPs.
Luckily, Wikipedia states "IDPs are issued by a national government directly, or through a network of AIT/FIA organizations or by any association duly empowered thereto by such other Contracting Party" (my emphasis). AIT/FIA has a website for finding such organizations and lists four in India:

Automobile Association of Southern India
India Automobile Association
Automobile Association of Upper India
Automobile Association of Eastern India

You could try contacting one of these.

IDP's purpose is to serve as a translation of your national license to the standardized classes, and to a language expected to be understood in the country of destination. In Japan (and many other countries), many may not understand English or be able to easily read English documents. A standard IDP booklet provided by AAA in the US, for example, has a Japanese version included (together with Chinese, Arabic, Russian, and several Latin-scripted languages).
That may be one reason your version may be refused by agencies in Japan.
Another is that your version doesn't have any driving classes marked (listed above, but not marked in any of the squares, which is where they'd expect it).

Yes, I understand. Do you think I should try with private organizations issuing IDP?  The IDP they give do has booklet format. But since they are not official government doc, I am little skeptical about their acceptance

@Ninjahattori IDP doesn't have to be issued by a government agency, and in many countries they aren't (e.g. AAA in the USA). But they have to be duly authorized by the government.

Oh Is that the case? I see.

How can I get it "duly authorized" by the government then? What are the ways?

@Ninjahattori ask at your local DMV who's authorized to issue IDPs, I guess?

ah, don't think they will support this. They will argument that they themselves issue the IDP(wrong format tho) then why would they attest some other source's

It appears that folks mentioned at least one other organization in India that provides IDP.

Oh, u mean the " Automobile Association of Upper India"? I am afraid it is a private org only

It's listed on the AAA page, so seems legit: https://exchange.aaa.com/international-travel/international-clubs/ . Not sure what "private org" means to you. It's not part of the government.

Oh I see. Are there any success stories known by you for the AAUI by any chance? I am a little afraid that even after paying their (high) fees, I might not be allowed at the shop. That would be troublesome.

@Ninjahattori when littleadv says “it has to be duly authorised by the government”, it = the local AA, not it = the IDP. You can find the list of authorised providers on the FIA’s dedicated website: https://internationaldrivingpermit.org

The internation treaty which governs the issuance of this kind of IDPs (the 1949 Geneva Convention) does not require the document to be in Japanese.  Your IDP is potentially non-conforming with regard to that treaty if there's no other side to the document you showed here because the treaty requires, among other things, some write-up in each of Arabic, Chinese, English, Russian,  Spanish and French, with French coming last; but even this is not required for the "inscriptions" on the page with your personal data where any Latin script based language (such as English) will do.
In my country, the application form asks me about the coutries I intend to visit.  If I answer "Iceland" but don't mention Japan, I receive an IDP in booklet form in about 10 languages including Icelandic but excluding Japanese.  And vice versa; the languages are tailored to the destination.  The resulting IDP is equally valid in Iceland and Japan either way, just maybe not equally convenient.
For IDPs issued in Australia, the set of 9 languages is fixed and it always includes Japanese.
The AAA (in the USA) issues the IDP in a fixed set of 10 or 11 languages, and some sources list the languages specifically without mentioning Japanese.  (So perhaps Japanese was added or removed at some point.)  You can bet that there were many American tourists driving in Japan without any issue ever since the 1949 Geneva Convention about the issuance of IDP came into effect.
This latest example that doesn't include any Japanese on the IDP is, in your situation, somewhat comparable to your Indian form 4A which doesn't let you specify your country of destination and you get issued an IDP in languages that don't include Japanese, although keeping it English-only is admittedly stretching the established rules even further.
All you need to do is to find a car rental in Tokyo that understands written English and that's not going to be insurmountable.  You want to reserve your car rental in advance anyway, so make sure you clarify this point with the specific agency before you pay anything.
Ultimately, the car rental agency is not required to check your drive permit to any specific degree.  All they need to know is that their car will be safe in their customer's hands.  Each car rental agency has slightly different paperwork prepared for you to confirm just that.
Remember that the IDP is always used together with your local (Indian) driver's license.  The document that's eventually accepted (or rejected) as your permit to drive in Japan is the local license, and the IDP is just auxiliary.
As littleadv's answer already mentioned, the perhaps biggest screw-up by your issuer is that they marked the vehicle classes you are allowed to drive in a non-conforming manner, creating a yet another obstacle to understanding.  However, if this is all that your local authority gave you, you do nothing wrong if you use the document for its intended purpose.
Drive safely and have fun.

I have an AAA's IDP issued this year, and it most definitely includes Japanese.
